# The tooltip is not visible when I click the icon. How can I fix this code so that it is visible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip

I have made an abbreviations list so that when a user clicks the clipboard icon, the abbreviation definition will be copied to the clipboard. I added a tooltip that appears on clicking the icon saying 'Copied' to alert the user. However, I cannot figure out why the tooltip is not visible when I click the icon. Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  /* COPY TO CLIPBOARD */

  // click the icon
  $(".copy-icon").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Find the parent list item
    let listItem = $(this).closest("li");

    // Find the abbreviation and definition within the list item
    let abbreviation = listItem.find("p").text();

    // Create a temporary input element
    let $temp = $("<input>");
    $("body").append($temp);
    $temp.val(abbreviation).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();

    // Show the tooltip
    let tooltip = $("<span class='tooltip'>Copied</span>");
    listItem.append(tooltip);

    // Remove the tooltip after 1 second
    setTimeout(function () {
      tooltip.remove();
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  background-color: #f0f0f0; /* Background color for the body */
}

/* Centering content */
.center {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

/* Container for the abbreviations list */
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); /* Two columns for two rows */
  gap: 20px; /* Adjust the gap as needed */
  justify-content: center; /* Center the columns horizontally */
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  padding: 0 20px; /* Add padding to the sides */
}

/* Abbreviations list row */
.abbreviations-row {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Abbreviation list item */
.abbreviations-list li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fff; /* Background color for list items */
  border: 1px solid #ccc; /* Border for list items */
  border-radius: 8px; /* Rounded corners for list items */
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

/* Copy icon */
.copy-icon {
  color: #2a7475;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-right: 10px; /* Spacing between icon and text */
  cursor: pointer;
}

.copy-icon:hover {
  transform: translateY(-4px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.abbreviations-list li {
  position: relative; /* Add this line to set a non-static position */
  /* ... Other styles ... */
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: #373737;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1; /* Ensure tooltip appears above other elements */
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.tooltip.appear {
  animation: appear 1s ease;
}

@keyframes appear {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Abbreviations List</title>
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <h3>Abbreviations List</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="center">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="abbreviations-row">
          <ul class="abbreviations-list">
            <li>
              <span class="tooltip">Copied</span>
              <i class="material-icons copy-icon">content_copy</i>
              <p>ACR, American College of Rheumatology criteria</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span class="tooltip">Copied</span>
              <i class="material-icons copy-icon">content_copy</i>
              <p>AE, adverse event</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span class="tooltip">Copied</span>
              <i class="material-icons copy-icon">content_copy</i>
              <p>AS, ankylosing spondylitis</p>
            </li>
            <!-- Add more abbreviations as needed -->
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="abbreviations-row">
          <ul class="abbreviations-list">
            <li>
              <span class="tooltip">Copied</span>
              <i class="material-icons copy-icon">content_copy</i>
              <p>
                ACR 20/50/70, ≥20/≥50/≥70% response in the American College of
                Rheumatology criteria
              </p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span class="tooltip">Copied</span>
              <i class="material-icons copy-icon">content_copy</i>
              <p>API, abbreviated prescribing information</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span class="tooltip">Copied</span>
              <i class="material-icons copy-icon">content_copy</i>
              <p>ASAS, Assessment of SpondyloArthritis international Society</p>
            </li>
            <!-- Add more abbreviations as needed -->
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have asked chatgpt what is wrong with the code and it says nothing is wrong and the tooltip should be visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a tooltip class with the opacity of 0 and you override it by adding the appear class. However, when you append your dynamic tooltip, you never add the appear class.

Instead of fixing that, I simply removed that code and reused the tooltip span that already exists in your HTML. There was no reason to recreate it. I simply used listitem to find the child of tooltip and added the appear class. I removed the timeout since your appear and tooltip has a transition that changes the opacity after a second anyway.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  /* COPY TO CLIPBOARD */

  // click the icon
  $(".copy-icon").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Find the parent list item
    let listItem = $(this).closest("li");

    // Find the abbreviation and definition within the list item
    let abbreviation = listItem.find("p").text();

    // Create a temporary input element
    let $temp = $("<input>");
    $("body").append($temp);
    $temp.val(abbreviation).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();

    // Show the tooltip
    listItem.find(".tooltip").addClass("appear")
  });
});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  background-color: #f0f0f0; /* Background color for the body */
}

/* Centering content */
.center {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

/* Container for the abbreviations list */
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); /* Two columns for two rows */
  gap: 20px; /* Adjust the gap as needed */
  justify-content: center; /* Center the columns horizontally */
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  padding: 0 20px; /* Add padding to the sides */
}

/* Abbreviations list row */
.abbreviations-row {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Abbreviation list item */
.abbreviations-list li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fff; /* Background color for list items */
  border: 1px solid #ccc; /* Border for list items */
  border-radius: 8px; /* Rounded corners for list items */
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

/* Copy icon */
.copy-icon {
  color: #2a7475;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-right: 10px; /* Spacing between icon and text */
  cursor: pointer;
}

.copy-icon:hover {
  transform: translateY(-4px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.abbreviations-list li {
  position: relative; /* Add this line to set a non-static position */
  /* ... Other styles ... */
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: #373737;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1; /* Ensure tooltip appears above other elements */
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.tooltip.appear {
  animation: appear 1s ease;
}

@keyframes appear {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Abbreviations List</title>
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <h3>Abbreviations List</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="center">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="abbreviations-row">
          <ul class="abbreviations-list">
            <li>
              <span class="tooltip">Copied</span>
              <i class="material-icons copy-icon">content_copy</i>
              <p>ACR, American College of Rheumatology criteria</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span class="tooltip">Copied</span>
              <i class="material-icons copy-icon">content_copy</i>
              <p>AE, adverse event</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span class="tooltip">Copied</span>
              <i class="material-icons copy-icon">content_copy</i>
              <p>AS, ankylosing spondylitis</p>
            </li>
            <!-- Add more abbreviations as needed -->
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="abbreviations-row">
          <ul class="abbreviations-list">
            <li>
              <span class="tooltip">Copied</span>
              <i class="material-icons copy-icon">content_copy</i>
              <p>
                ACR 20/50/70, ≥20/≥50/≥70% response in the American College of
                Rheumatology criteria
              </p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span class="tooltip">Copied</span>
              <i class="material-icons copy-icon">content_copy</i>
              <p>API, abbreviated prescribing information</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span class="tooltip">Copied</span>
              <i class="material-icons copy-icon">content_copy</i>
              <p>ASAS, Assessment of SpondyloArthritis international Society</p>
            </li>
            <!-- Add more abbreviations as needed -->
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```